# Nodejs page (HTML) conversion, like how to changing the page when I click a button in main page jump to login page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

In my router code, I have something like below. In my main page, I have a button to jump to login page, that is work with out nodejs, but after I connect the node.js code, only show me the main page, if I click the login button, the page will show be that `Cannot GET /LoginPage.html`. How to fix that?

```
const express = require('express')


const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('HomePage.html', {
        title: 'Hello World'
    })
})
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('LoginPage.html', {
        title: 'Hello World'
    })
})
```

In the app.js code:

```
const passport = require('passport')
const flash = require('express-flash')
const session = require('express-session')
const multer = require('multer');
const GridFsStorage = require("multer-gridfs-storage");
const path = require('path')
const cors = require('cors')
const crypto = require("crypto");
const favicon = require('serve-favicon')


const app = express(); 


const User = require('./models/user')
   
const router = require('./router')

app.engine('html', require( 'express-art-template'))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use('/node_modules/', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'))

app.use(cors());

app.use(router)

app.listen(4001, (req, res) => {
    console.log('port xxxx')
})
```

In the HTML code, just click the button, and jump to Loginpage.html

```
 <a href="./LoginPage.html"> Login</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things,

1. you have 2 same endpoints `router.get('/',`
2. So change the second route to something like `router.get('/login',`
3. you should access your login page now on /login

You are getting `Cannot GET /LoginPage.html` because there is no route LoginPage.html in your backend

Comment: I try, but still doesn't work, I upload some detail, Hoping is useful.

Comment: You are trying to render /LoginPage.html which is not there, update your a tag with <a href="/login"> Login</a>

Answer (score 0):

First thing is the way you defined the routes is wrong as you have 2 same end points.Try to change the login endpoint as **/login** in your .js file.

You need to change the html file also as you are trying to call directly the html file not the api end point **/login**.You need to call to the node backend endpoint which renders the desired html file.
 not the direct reference to html file.

**Edit 1:**
Please do the following:

Change your app.js file like below:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const router = require('./router');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');

app.engine('html', require('express-art-template'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(cors());

app.use(router);

app.listen(4001, (req, res) => {
  console.log('port 4001');
});
```

And the router.js to like this

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index.html', {
    title: 'Hello World',
  });
});
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login.html', {
    title: 'Hello World',
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And create a public folder and create 2 html files index.html and login.html. Your app structure should be like below:

```
--public
-------+ index.html
-------+ login.html
-- app.js
--router.js
--package.json
```

I tried this it worked for me. Change the variables and other file names as per your need. I guess your folder structure and the way you are rendering is wrong.Hopefully it should work.

Comment: I did change router.get('/login', (req, res) => { res.render('LoginPage.html'------, what do I still need to change?

Comment: @LeeAlex  can you tell me what is the issue you are getting now.

Comment: Still the same issue, Cannot GET /LoginPage.html. The only cheng is " router.get('/login' ", do I need to change anything in HTML or the app.js?

Comment: @LeeAlex I have edited the answer above.Please do check that

Comment: I tried, and also get the same issue. I upload my code above, hope can find what happen.

Comment: @LeeAlex in the router file please export that router like i did in my code snippet.